# NameError: name 'rank' is not defined even though i have mentioned it in global

Tags: python, class, global, nameerror

The code below is a simplified version of a bigger code. The main action i want to perform is to use and change `rank` and `progress` inside the `inc_progress(self)` function.

```
class User:
    rank=-8
    progress=0
    def inc_progress(self):
        global rank, progress
        rank+=1
        print(rank,progress)



u=User()
u.inc_progress()
```

but it gives me the error: `NameError: name 'rank' is not defined. Did you mean: 'range'?`

does anyone know a possible fix for this issue, so that I can use and change the values of `rank` and `progress` in the `inc_progress(self)` function

Comment: You may be confusing global, class and instance.

Comment: Classes do not define any scope; `rank` is a class attribute, not a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining `rank` and `progress` outside of `__init__`, you've defined them as class variables, meaning that they belong to the class and will be available to all instances of that class. https://pynative.com/python-class-variables/

Here's a modified version of your code that does what you're expecting (and probably some things that you aren't!)

```
class User:
rank=-8
progress=0
def inc_progress(self):
    User.rank+=1
    print(User.rank, User.progress)

u=User()
u.inc_progress() # Output: -7, 0
```

Ok great! Problem solved, right? Well, maybe. Look at this.

```
u=User()
u.inc_progress() # Output: -7, 0
u2 = User()
print(u2.rank, u2.progress) # Output: -7, 0
```

Wait, what? That newly created instance of `User` has rank=-7 instead of -8! That's class variables for you. If you want `rank` and `progress` to be specific to the instance, then define them during initialization and access them as usual with `self`

```
class User:
def __init__(self):
    self.rank=-8
    self.progress=0
def inc_progress(self):
    self.rank+=1
    print(self.rank, self.progress)

u=User()
u.inc_progress() # Output: -7, 0
u2 = User()
print(u2.rank, u2.progress) # Output: -8, 0
```